# Does the parent of a Variable class need to be exclusively a Tk instance?

Tags: python, tkinter

The [Variable classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) in most examples I've seen are instantiated without an explicit parent(e.g `var = tk.StringVar()`), which I assume as most other widgets(if not all) is defaulting to the current `Tk` instance, usually put in the variable `root`. Which is why I'm uncertain if its parent exclusively needs to be a(usually the current, and only) `Tk` instance or if it can be *any* widget.

Does the parent of a variable class need to be exclusively a Tk instance? Additionally, is there anything wrong with any of the attributes of the class below?:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


class MyEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.var1 = tk.BooleanVar(self)
        # parent is exclusively the Entry widget
        self.var2 = tk.DoubleVar(master)
        # parent is master widget, not necessarily a Tk instance
        self.var3 = tk.IntVar()
        # parent is exclusively the current Tk instance, implicitly
        self.var4 = tk.StringVar(self._root())
        # parent is the Tk instance MyEntry object is a (grand)child of, exclusively


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    entry = MyEntry(frame)
    frame.pack()
    entry.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: My _guess_ is that the supplied parent is irrelevant, the Var is only interested in the `.` root object.

Comment: It can be any widget, and it will have the same effect as using the Tk instance that that widget uses. That said, good code will only have one Tk() instance, which the Variable will default to, so there should not be a need to provide anything.

Answer (score 1):

It can be any widget, but there's no advantage to it being anything other than the root widget. The implementation of the `Variable` class (from which `StringVar`, etc inherit) simply uses the given master to find the root window. The root window is all it actually cares about, and once it knows the root window, it doesn't use the master for anything else.

Comment: How about memory management? In the above code, may any of the variable class objects persist longer or cause some other kind of (higher, if any) memory leak as compared to the rest?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, the parent doesn't exclusively need to be a Tk instance.

In the docstring of all of the above-mentioned classes and their superclass `Variable` in the [source code](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter-pysrc.html) there's the line:

```
...
    def __init__(self, master=None, value=None, name=None):
        """Construct a string variable.

        MASTER can be given as master widget.
...
```

in which I assume `MASTER` refers to the argument `master`, indicates that master can be a widget unemphatically, so I'd assume the `master` to a variable class *can* be any widget.

---

I don't think anything's wrong with any of the Variable class instantiations, although some may be over-explicit and mostly redundant in most cases.

That being said, in the code provided, while all of them would be fine (widgets can't exist without a `Tk` instance anyway), I believe `self.var1 = tk.BooleanVar(self)` is the best-structured way of instantiating it in terms of OOP, because it allows the most `self`-contained approach:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


class MyEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.var1 = tk.BooleanVar(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry = MyEntry(root)
    entry.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```